# How do I enter the time value in hh:mm:ss format?

Tags: ios, cocoa, ios4, xcode4

I need to enter the time value hh:mm:ss `(09:45:56)` format , but in the Xcode text field I always get `(094556)` as format -
how to resolve this?

Comment: Why not use the [`UIDatePicker`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html)

Comment: just i need enter the time manually thats y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSDateFormatter` to parse any custom format

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

dateformatter.dateFormat = @"HH':'mm':'ss";

NSString *mydate = @"09:45:56" 

NSDate *parseddate = [dateformatter dateFromString:mydate];
```

This should give you a date of "9.45 am today"

The Docs for NSDateFormatter are pretty good but you can find the specific formatter variants possible here. Its linked from the apple docs.

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: parseddate=2000-01-01 04:15:56 +0000 not today date

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you want to format the text in HH:mm:ss format as it is being typed in a UITextField?

In that case, make your view controller a UITextFieldDelegate and implement this selector:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Every time the user types a character, or deletes it, this method will be called. At that point, you can determine whether to format the string. For instance, after they've typed the second character, thus creating the hour component of 09, you can append a ":" to the string so that it looks like "09:".

Another option. Use this selector to format it after they've finished typing in the entire string:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Comment: sorry i didnt understand this, any sample links?